# Is there any difference in using margin-top or padding-top on the BODY tag?

Tags: html, css

I am using a sticky navbar that's 70 pixels high. So in order for it to work and show the rest of the content properly, I am giving the `body` a `padding-top` (here, it comes ...or `margin-top`) of 70px.

Personally, the reason why I tried to use padding instead of margin is because my Google Autocomplete implementation inside a modal had issues when I used margin.

Is there any difference (or downside) in using padding or margin? Will I run into any other problems?

Comment: Margin is to separate an element from another element..padding is the space between the content of the element and its border.

Answer (score 1):

I think here you have some difficulty in understanding the difference between padding and margin

1. Margin is used to separate an element from another element

2.Padding is the distance between the content and the border

Check the following snippet

```css
#div-1{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:300px;
  margin-top:20px;
  padding:10px;
}

#div-2{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:300px;
  margin-top:20px;
 padding-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  Div1
</div>

<div id="div-2">
  Div1
</div>
```

The above snippet is with padding and margin

Consider this without margin

```css
#div-1{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:300px;
  
  padding:10px;
}

#div-2{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:300px;
 padding-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  Div1
</div>

<div id="div-2">
  Div1
</div>
```

consider this one without padding

```css
#div-1{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:300px;
 
}

#div-2{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  Div1
</div>

<div id="div-2">
  Div1
</div>
```

Hope these snippets help you in understanding margin and padding